# Can I temporarily use device with physical QWERTY in touch only mode?

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen

I am looking for a new phone with a physical QWERTY keyboard (probably a "slide-down" construction). As I do not have possibility to test it, I would like to know, whether I can use the device as a standard touch phone without using the physical keyboard if needed.

How does Android behave when the physical keyboard is not activated (the slide-down phone is folded)? Do I have to manually activate the virtual one or is it automatic?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the phone should behave same as without physical keyboard until you open the physical keyboard which will cause hiding the virtual one.